# Ubuntu 14.04 SLI flicker

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, gpu

I keep getting a lot of flickering and artifacts the moment I enable sli. Tried updating the nvidia drivers but the problem remains. Is there a possible fix or work around? I'm running gtx 760s.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If you set the SLI to SFR the flickering goes away, but I have another application that is now having trouble after that change and I'm not sure why. You can give it a shot though.

Comment: I tried SFR already.Unfortunately doesn't work for me :-(